# Log ssh commands on client

Tags: ssh

How can I log all executed commands over SSH on the client machine?

Let's say I'm making a connection to example.com and type the following commands:

```
$ ls
$ touch hello
$ mkdir world
$ mv hello world/
```

I want on my client to have all typed commands in a file like this:

```
ls
touch hello
mkdir world
mv hello world/
```

My goal is if I make a mistake and break the server, I still can search which command goes wrong. I can't use `~/.bash_logout` to save commands after disconnection nor `~/.bash_history` because it's server-side. I didn't find anything relevant with `~/.ssh/config` so I'm asking here.

Any idea?

EDIT:

To be more clear, if I connect from machine A to machine B, I want to have the history file on machine A.

Answer (score 0):

It most cases, this will already in your history file, e.g. `~/.bash_history`

Comment: `~/.bash_history` is on the server side, not on the client side. If I close the connection, I can't check which commands I have typed.

Answer (score 0):

you can find all commands you have typed by history or cat ~/.bash_history or even if you want  redirect output of that command to a file you can write 
cat ~/.bash_history > your file name 
your file name is a file that you want to save history in that file 
or if you want to review last n command that you have typed from history you can type  history | tail -n and you can redirect them to a file by typing history | tail -n > your_file_name

Comment: ~/.bash_history is on the server side, not on the client side. If I close the connection, I can't check which commands I have typed.

Answer (score 0):

This can done by adding following line in the `/etc/bashrc` file

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ][0-9]+[ ]//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
```

you also have to create a file `commands.conf` within the `/etc/rsyslog.d/` directory and the contents of the file should be like:

```
local6.*    /var/log/commands.log
```

Then restart `rsyslog` service 
All log will be capture in `/var/log/commands.log`

Comment: If I connect to B with A, will the file be on A?

Comment: No. its system file, Not user based. put into /etc/bashrc. and work for all users.

Comment: @wqeqwsd please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: As I need the file to be on the client side, unfortunately it does not help me